# API request json convertion to JS object

Tags: javascript, json, api, web

I am trying to create a simple AJAX request to AccuWeather but the JSON method won't convert the returned data to a JS object.

All I get is:

> Status_code: "JSON_VALIDATION",
>   status_msg: "Syntax error. Incorrect input JSON. Please, check fields with JSON input."*

What I do wrong?

```js
async function getWeather() {
  try {
    const request = await fetch(
      'https://accuweatherstefan-skliarovv1.p.rapidapi.com/searchByLocationKey', {
        'method': 'post',
        'headers': {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'AccuWeatherstefan-skliarovV1.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': '...',
          'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        'body': {
          'locationkey': 'IL',
          'apiKey': 'xxxxx'
        }
      }
    );
    const data = await request.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
}
getWeather();
getWeather('IL').then(resolved => {
  console.log(resolved);
});
```

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(request)` just after the `fetch` call and before calling `.json`?

Comment: I get the AJAX response in the JSON format (Readable stream) @Addis

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the conversion of the json response, but with sending the request. You can't send an object in body, you should send a JSON string, or in your case, create a formdata object:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('locationkey', 'IL');
formData.append('apiKey', 'apiKey');
```

and pass it as body:

```
const request = await fetch(
    'https://accuweatherstefan-skliarovv1.p.rapidapi.com/searchByLocationKey',
    {
        'method': 'post',
        'headers': {
            'x-rapidapi-host': 'AccuWeatherstefan-skliarovV1.p.rapidapi.com',
            'x-rapidapi-key': '...',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        'body': formData
    }
);
```